# how to change the font in the TreeView to display as same as the left webpage?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmWZQ.png)

the fonts in the TreeView and the Web page displayed in the treeview display different, I want display in the TreeView as same as webpage, how can I do ?

Comment: Not easy to achieve because they use different technologies and there are many factors involved. You have to create the font by calling the `CreateFont()` or `CreateFontIndirect()` function (same font name as the one used in the web page) and then change the font of the control by sending a `WM_SETFONT` or calling `CWnd`'s `SetFont()` function. Check the documentation of the font creation functions, esp what a positive vs negative font height means. Still, the result may be affected by the UI's scaling as well as the browser's scaling.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not solved yet.
logFont.lfPitchAndFamily = FIXED_PITCH;
lstrcpy(logFont.lfFaceName, "FixedSys");
static HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);
SelectObject(hItemDC, hFont);
Of course, when using the above method, things get worse, my TreeView only shows part of it.

Comment: Why do you call SelectObject(hItemDC, hFont)? Is it an owner-drawn control? I think the best way to do this would be the SetFont() function (or the WM_SETETEXT message), called only once, during the dialog's initialization. And why a FIXED_PITCH font, and FixedSys particularly? The text in the pic, esp the www.it5e.com one is variable pitch. What's the font in the web page really? Also you seem to not have tried the height parameter. I would recommend creating a small test-project first (simply print some text) until you get the font creation part right.